# (null): "_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from: ERROR

Tags: facebook, ios6, sdk

I am trying to follow 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login-with-facebook-using-ios-sdk/ documentation to obtain access token to access facebook services on behalf of user.

After I add
        - (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error

and

```
    - (BOOL)openSessionWithAllowLoginUI:(BOOL)allowLoginUI {
    return [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil
                                          allowLoginUI:allowLoginUI
                                     completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                         FBSessionState state,
                                                         NSError *error) {
                                         [self sessionStateChanged:session
                                                             state:state
                                                             error:error];
                                     }];
    }
```

I am getting **(null): "_ACFacebookAppIdKey", referenced from: ERROR** and they are 24 of those. I am not sure what exactly is going on.

Could someone help me out figure this thing out ?

Thank you

Comment: Well, adding 2 additional frameworks AdSupport, Accounts now the errors are down to 16 from 24 and the above error is gone. Now I get the below error.

Comment: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_sqlite3_bind_double", referenced from:
      -[FBCacheIndex _updateEntryInDatabaseForKey:entry:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)
      -[FBCacheIndex _writeEntryInDatabase:] in FacebookSDK(FBCacheIndex.o)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. It's mainly missing out the frameworks. According to the

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/getting-started/facebook-sdk-for-ios/ documentation,

we need to add 3 frameworks ( AdSupport, Accounts, Social). However, we should add one more to the list **libsqllite3.dylib** along with the above 3 to the framework folder.